# Modo de usar OfType

Tags: c#, linq

En un solo Oftype se pueden hacer varias búsquedas como TextBox, ComboBox, etc

```
foreach (Control c in frm.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
```

Deseo lograr algo como esto

```
foreach (Control c in frm.Controls.OfType<TextBox || TextBox || CheckBox>())
```

¿Se puede buscar por varios controles?

Comment: @sstan Hola, ya modifique la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como indica @sstan no es posible usar OfType para filtrar por varios tipos de controles. Modificaría su código agregando Cast()

```
foreach (Control c in frm.Controls.Cast<Control>().Where(ctl => ctl is TextBox || ctl is CheckBox))
```

También puedes declararte un método de extensión para realizar un filtro por varios tipos de controle más o menos así

```
using System.Collections;

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable OfType<T1, T2>(this IEnumerable source)
    {
        foreach (object item in source)
        {
            if (item is T1 || item is T2)
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, no es posible de combinar varios tipos con `OfType`. Para hacer lo que quieres, tendrías que convertir la logica usando `Where`:

```
foreach (Control c in frm.Controls.Where(ctl => ctl is TextBox || ctl is CheckBox))
```